# Dragilev method

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

What are the advantages and disadvantages of the Dragilev ( http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?&personid=32359&option_lang=eng 
and http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/search/?q=au%3A%22dragilev%2C%20a*%20v*%22 ) method for solving of systems of nonlinear equations?
The googling of "Dragilev" and "Draghilev" produces poor infoformation.  I also find a bit about that in http://forum.exponenta.ru/viewtopic.php?t=3892. Up to one of the coauthors,  the recent article http://jap.aip.org/resource/1/japiau/v113/i8/p083103_s1?isAuthorized=no uses the Dragilev method.

Answer (score 3):

These are two different methods of one author. One method relates to the theory of differential equations, another method of numerical-analytical method for solving systems of nonlinear equations. In Russian: Драгилев Анатолий Владимирович, 1923-1997.

Comment: Here are some of the applications of the basic idea of the “second”  method Draghilev and numerical methods.  Spatial linkages, animation,  geodesics on surfaces in R^n (n>=3), parallel curves on surfaces…
http://www.exponenta.ru/educat/systemat/selitskiy-ivanov/index.asp
http://vk.com/id242471809
Sorry, but in Russian.

Answer (score 0):

And
Universal method of kinematic analysis of spatial and planar link mechanisms http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=154228
Some examples 
http://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/204684-Lever-Mechanisms-